# How can I use Scanner in Java to read specific characters in a text file?

Tags: java, file, text, char

Basically, I am trying to read 4 characters from a sequential text file. The first two are ints that I will declare to a variable, and the next 2 are characters that I need to either assign to a String or a character so I can print them out later.

I know how to get the ints, but my main problem with reading the characters is that I am not sure how to, and there is a possibility that ones of the characters can be a ' ', or just a space. I have no idea how I'm supposed to get a space as a character. I need to use the characters later in the program to print something.

So far I've pretty much just done something like

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("textfile.txt"));

int a = s.nextInt();
int b = s.nextInt();
```

But then I get errors if I try to use next, especially if I'm trying to get a ' ' character. Any help please?

Comment: You probably have to use a lower level utility (`InputStreamReader`), since `Scanner` is a high level utility that parses data based on delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to get the next character using Scanner but if I'm in the same situation I'll just use nextLine() and then operate on the string I obtained. You can use charAt() to get specific characters. Much like:

```
String str = s.nextLine();

char c1 = str.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense that attempting to use `next()` to read a space character would not work, as it is the default delimiter character.

You can change the delimiter to something that should not occur in your input data by using `Scanner.useDelimiter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading 4 sequential characters, you are better off using InputStreamReader.

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("textfile.txt")));

int a = in.read()
int b = in.read()
char c = (char)in.read()
char d = (char)in.read()
```

If you are only working with ASCII characters, then you can skip InputStreamReader and use FileInputStream directly.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `read()` reads a single character. What would happen with an input of `5030XY`?

Comment: You are exactly right. This will read 5, 0, '3', and '0'. But as the question says, the format is 4 characters in sequence, 2 of which are ints. I took that to mean 2 single digit integers. Otherwise it is impossible to know how long the integers are.